# URL Validation procedure Testing

Tags: c#, regex, unit-testing, validation, testing

We're writing unit-tests for our URL validation method, and we're unsure if we're even testing the correct cases, so that's basically the first question; *Should* www.google actually return false, or would that actually be an Acceptable URL for a link?

We came up with the following cases, and their expected outcome, commented with the ones that fail the test:

```
[TestCase("http://www.google.com",true)]
[TestCase("https://www.google.com",true)]
[TestCase("www.google.com",true)]
[TestCase("http://google.com",true)]
[TestCase("google.com",true)]
[TestCase("http://www.google.co.uk", true)] //Fails, returns false
[TestCase("htp://www.google.com",false)]
[TestCase("http://www.google.dk", true)]
[TestCase("http://www.google", false)] 
[TestCase("http://google", false)]
[TestCase("wwww.google.com", false)] 
[TestCase("www.google", false)]
[TestCase("google", false)]
```

And are currently using this method in C#:

```
public bool IsTargetLinkValid(string targetLink)
{
  if (!targetLink.StartsWith("http://") && !targetLink.StartsWith("https://"))
    targetLink = "http://" + targetLink;

  return Regex.IsMatch(targetLink, @"^(http|http(s)?:\/\/)?(w{3})?\.?[\w-]+?(\.com|\.in|\.org|\.dk)");
}
```

Appending the http as part of the if statement does not change results of the tests.

First:
Are those test cases correct? Are some of them unnecessary?

Second:
Assuming they are correct, how do we get the final three to pass?

It should also be noted, that a specific top domain should not be tested for; Spanish or German domains should be fine too, and adding checks for all top level domains seems...exhaustive, if simply added to the regex

Keep in mind, these URL should eventually be used as for links from an advert, in a closed system (but still internationally accessible)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this regex [`^(http|http(s)?:\/\/)?(w{3})?\.?[\w-]+(\.com|\.in|\.org|\.dk)$`](https://regex101.com/r/2iZVnu/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so @Thefourthbird gave some better regex, but ultimately, the first question was the important one. We talked to a more experienced dev, who essentially said "Don't check top level domains, there are too many", so that's what we're doing.

The cases are currently:

```
[TestCase("http://www.google.com",true)]
[TestCase("https://www.google.com",true)]
[TestCase("www.google.com",true)]
[TestCase("http://google.com",true)]
[TestCase("google.com",true)]
[TestCase("htp://www.google.com",false)]
[TestCase("http://www.google.co.uk", true)]
[TestCase("http://www.google.dk", true)]
[TestCase("http://www.google", true)]
[TestCase("http://google", false)]
[TestCase("wwww.google.com", true)]
[TestCase("www.google", true)]
[TestCase("google", false)]
```

They all pass, with this regex [^(http|http(s)?://)?([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+[.com|.in|.org]+([\?%&=]*)?](https://regex101.com/r/QkYoIC/1/)

...with inspiration from @fourth.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this regex [`^(http|http(s)?:\/\/)?(w{3})?\.?[\w-]+(\.com|\.in|\.org|\.dk)$`](https://regex101.com/r/2iZVnu/2/)

- from the beginning of the string `^`
- the optional protocol `(http|http(s)?:\/\/)?`
- optional www `(w{3})?`
- optional dot `\.?`
- one or more word characters/hyphen `[\w-]+`
- ending on `(\.com|\.in|\.org|\.dk)$`

Comment: We noticed however, that it now fails on any top level domains BUT the listed ones. Adding a case for www.google.co.uk, that we expect to be true, makes the test fail in that testcase. I've updated the test cases. It should not expect a specific top level domain, or a list of specifics.

Comment: Does this work for you? [`^(http|http(s)?:\/\/)?(w{3})?\.?[\w-]+(\.com|\.in|\.org|\.dk|\.co|\.uk)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/2iZVnu/3/)

Comment: It probably would, until we start testing for German domains, or Spanish. We need something that doesn't specifically require top level domains to be something specific. The regex in the question passed on the .dk domain test, without it being specified.

Answer (score 0):

The third last `wwww.google.com` returns true, because you auto-append the `http://`-prefix in your method.

Comment: Yes, but is it a valid testcase to begin with? Would you check for 4 w's at the start of the url? Also, running it without the auto appending http returns the same results. (I'm appending the question with this)

Comment: Oh, seems I overlooked the fourth w